# mysql insert problem

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysqli

ive got a really weird problem. i have no clue why its not working. i create an user and get the id and insert a row based on that id in another table. the row gets inserted with that id but the other values however for that row are not inserted!

```
 $user_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);

 $query = "INSERT INTO selections 
 (user_id, language_id, country_id, region_id, city_id, gender_id, age_id, category_id)
 VALUES ($user_id, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0)";
```

so the user_id gets inserted, but not the other values (they are all 0 in the table). i have really checked the columns and deleted all foreign keys to debug this problem. but i have no clue at all.

the columns are all INT. the weird part is sometime when i replace $user_id with a literal number it works, sometimes it doesnt. but the row is always created. and i have checked that $user_id is an integer.

i know this is a hard problem and that it can be caused of a lot of things, but i have tried to solve this tiny issue for 3 hours now. so would be great if someone just gave me something i could do to debug this problem.

UPDATE: even when i have set default values and just insert the first column (user_id) it doesnt work. every other field is 0. So weird!

```
| selections | CREATE TABLE `selections` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `region_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gender_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `age_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


  $query = "INSERT INTO selections
        (user_id)
        VALUES ('$user_id')";
```

the user_id shows 178 and other fields are 0:(

### UPDATE:

It worked in the sql command line. but not in php. but mysqli generated no error and the row was indeed inserted but why are the other fields 0?

ANSWER: My fault. i had a jquery script that changed it back to 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. There's a lot of AJAX on my page so it was tricky to find it...sorry my bad!

Comment: Can you get us the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE selections; in MySQL?

Comment: Have you checked that the `mysqli_query()` or whatnot calls actually *succeed*?

Comment: Have you tried to append the user id via `( " .$userid . ",....`?

Comment: Do the table already contain a row with that user_id ?

Comment: so weird.even when i have default values and then just insert user_id it doesnt work. every field is 0.

Comment: Post the output from these statements: `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`
and `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;`  Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run into situations like this, print the query to screen before it is executed:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ...";
echo $query
```

Try:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO selections 
            (user_id, language_id, country_id, region_id, city_id, gender_id, age_id, category_id)
          VALUES 
            ({$user_id}, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0)";
```

You need to wrap PHP variables in {} when referencing them in SQL string statements.

### Use Your DEFAULT Constraints

---

If you have defaults then you don't need to set the values in your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO selections 
  (user_id)
VALUES 
  ({$user_id})
```

### Referencial Integrity

---

You're getting the last inserted id and using it in a subsequent insert into another table, but you don't have a foreign key defined on the `user_id` column to ensure that the value going into that column actually exists in the other table.  If you provide the name of the table & column you are getting for your last insert id, I'll provide the [ALTER TABLE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: Yes, definitely echo the $query, then try loading up a MySQL console and running that query and see what happens.
Other thing I'd suggest is to set your SQL mode to Strict, MySQL has different modes some will insets 0 to a variable on error and give a warning, others will stop the insert all together if there is an error, you probably want a strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO selections 
(user_id, language_id, country_id, region_id, city_id, gender_id, age_id, category_id)
VALUES ('$user_id', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0)";
```

Single quotes around $user_id might do it.

Comment: That would be correct if the `user_id` column were a string related data type (text, varchar)